# jQuery find word in JSON object

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to determine when or not a JSON object contains the word "cinema".

It is accessible through `"obj.message"` so the check would be something like:

```
Pseudo-code - if (obj.message contains "cinema") display it
```

Is it possible to find text within a JSON object?

Thanks

Comment: I think you don't have a JSON object, but a JavaScript object. http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
alert(obj.message.indexOf("cinema") != -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is obj.message itself an object?  If so, the word is "in":  `if ("cinema" in obj.message)...` .
Or is obj.message an string?  Then it's `indexOf`, as Jacek_FH wrote.

Comment: obj.message is an object as far as i know!

Comment: @benhowdle89: Give us an example of the value of `obj.message`.

Comment: ok so, its pulling back tweets so one was this: "Very cool... via Jimena Espinosa" and one "third film in a row at the cinema that I've fallen asleep through...awkward !" so in the first, obj.message did not contain the word "cinema"

Comment: You want indexOf, as Jacek_FH said.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(obj.message.match(/cinema/))
```

would that work?